# Different Plot Filling for multiple curves

Tags: plotting

*Warning: possibly dumb question :-(*

I have two functions I want to plot with the `Filling` option, like:

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]
```

That's OK. But if I only want the sine filled, and try

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> {Axis, None}]
```

MMA returns error messages that `Axis` and `None` are not valid Filling specifications. How can I selectively apply `Filling`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember to look in the documentation when facing problems like this. Most options are well documented. For this case you could go to [Filling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html) and see that it states:

{i1->p1,i2->p2,...} fill from object ik to pk

So for your case you would write:

```
 Plot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]
```

Comment: Thanks, jVincent. Easier than I anticipated. @J.M. - I *had* looked in the documentation, but stumbled over the fifth bullet item. Probably expected something more sophisticated.